Engagement App campaigns in Google ads are taking users to 404 page when app opens
I am trying to stitch user journey for my engagement campaign from Youtube Ads (primarily running App Engagement campaign in Google ads) and have integrated custom scheme uri for deep links, but we are not able to send user to the page dedicated for them to interact on the Android app page, campaigns are throwing 404 on my android app this only happens when running app campaigns. Any guidance will be appreciated.
I tried all the types of deeplink integration and along with App links for android but we are not able to send users to specific page on the Android app.
